# DHCP not working after NetBIOS over TCP/IP disabled

Tags: dhcp, tcpip, netbios

I want to disable the "NetBIOS over TCP/IP" device in the device manager to free port 445. But after doing that my Internet stops working. I'm connected to a WLan router using DHCP on WinXP, and it is stuck forever in the "acquire network address" step.

Why does it misbehave like that? I don't need NetBIOS!

Answer (score 1):

NetBios uses [ports 137, 138, and 139](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS_over_TCP/IP).  Port 445 information is utilized by SMB over TCP. The SMB (Server Message Block) protocol is used among other things for file sharing.

Have you tried [direct hosting of SMB over TCP/IP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204279)?

Comment: "disabling on DHCP server" presumes a Windows product serving DHCP.  i'm not sure how many WLAN routers run Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Good point...I'll remove it from my response.

Comment: I'll try that, but I doubt it will free the listening port 445 on my machine. 
I disabled the "NetBIOS over TCP/IP" device only because someone said it would free port 445.
I checked the services, and "DHCP" depends on the "NetBIOS over TCP/IP" service, which might explain why my internet stopped working. Configuring a static IP configuration to circumvent DHCP didn't help, though.

Comment: @user, You say configuring a static IP didn't help.  Where are you getting your DHCP from?  Your ISP?  A local router?